# what is the best way to handle npm packages with meteor 1.4

Tags: meteor, deployment, npm

i'm now made a great upgrade for my app from meteor 1.3 to 1.4 and also upgrade node and other packages.
and I just think now what i can rebuild better and what improvements i can do to be more appropriate with the new version.

my specific question is how need i handle all npm dependencies in production with meteor 1.4.
meteor npm? npm-container?
(i'm use Mup for deployment)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have installed the npm packages with

```
npm install --save package-name
```

or

```
meteor npm install --save package-name
```

Then your `package.json` file will be up to date, and your job is done.

Comment: is there any practical difference between those two commands?

Comment: To all practical purposes no, Meteor maintains it's own versions of node and npm, so that it has more control - so you might have different versions of node and npm installed, which could behave differently